# set edges invisible in vertices of the graph but visible everywhere else

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, graph

I am making a program using javafx where I can draw a graph.
So everything goes well but now I want the edges to be visible just in the pane, but invisible in each vertice. I know there is a way to do that in javafx using properties for example, but I'm a bit lost. Help!

Comment: I don't quite understand, what does this mean? => "I want the edges to be visible just in the pane, but invisible in each vertice"

Comment: How do you draw the edges/vertices? Show some code or at least add a good description of your approach. Otherwise it's extremely hard, if not impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What I can do is draw a Line between the center of two vertices OK? 
The fact is that I don't want to see the line in the vertice because it is weird, i want to see the Line as it started and ended from the edges of the vertices, not from the center. But that's just a visual effect.